# How to write a shell script to filter data based on the input

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

Below is the scenario:

> Given a file that contains a log (timestamp, customer id, page id), please write a script to parse it and output the list of pages visited by each customer.
>
> Input CSV File:
>
> ```
> Time, Customer ID, Page ID
>
> 1, C1, P1
> 2, C2, P2
> 3, C3, P3
> 4, C2, P1
> 5, C2, P3
> 6, C2, P2
> 7, C1, P3
> 8, C1, P2
> 9, C3, P1
> 10, C2, P1
> 11, C2, P3
> 12, C2, P2
> 13, C1, P1
> 14, C1, P3
> 15, C1, P2
> ```
>
> Example execution of script.  The Customer ID must be passed as a parameter. That is, `./script "C1"`
>
> Output:
>
> ```
> P1, P3, P2, P1, P3, P2
> ```

As of now, I got the following code to parse a CSV file

Code:

```
INPUT=/filepath/customers.csv
CUSTOMER_NAME=$1
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read f1 f2 f3
do
        echo "Time : $f1"
        echo "Customer ID : $f2"
        echo "Page_ID : $f3"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

How can I write the logic to filter the data based on the customer input?

Comment: Why don't you use [tag:awk] for this? Like `awk -F', ' -vq=C1 '$2==q{printf "%s%s",sep,$3;sep=FS} END{print ""}' file`, or keep pages in an array and join them in the END block

Answer (score 1):

Your scrip was not far from what you wanted.

Let's see what is missing:

- you read the customer ID in `$f2` but when reading, the space between comma and the customer name is stored in variable. (Check it with `echo "f2 is: \"$f2\""`).

  To remove the extra space, you can use `tr`: `CNAME=$(echo "$f2" | tr -d ' \t')` will remove space from `f2` and store the result in `CNAME`
- Once you've get the customer name from file, you can compare it with `CUSTOMER_NAME`
- For the output, you can store the pages index in a `RESULT` variable inserting the necessary comma.

So your script could looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
INPUT=customers.csv                                            
CUSTOMER_NAME=$1                                               
OLDIFS=$IFS                                                    
IFS=','         
RESULT=""
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }  
while read f1 f2 f3                                            
do                                                             
    CNAME=$(echo "$f2" | tr -d ' \t')                              
    if [ "$CNAME" = "$CUSTOMER_NAME" ]                         
    then                                                                   
        if [ -z "$RESULT" ] 
        then
            RESULT="$f3"
        else
            RESULT="$RESULT,$f3"
        fi
    fi                                                         
done < $INPUT                                                  
IFS=$OLDIFS
echo "$RESULT"
```

Note that if one of the customer ID has a space in it, this script won't work.

You should consider using `awk` as suggested in comments.